mySQL select IN range from two column
Is it possible to define a range for the IN part of the query from two-column, something like this
SELECT hotel, destination 
FROM mytable 
WHERE checkin, checkout IN (10..15);

instead of
SELECT hotel, destination 
FROM mytable 
WHERE checkin and checkout IN (10..15);


You can concatenate logical expressions, i.e.
SELECT hotel, destination FROM mytable WHERE checkin IN (10,15) OR checkout IN (10,15);


thanks this is realy helpfull
